# Plotting a function variable vs. an explicit function

Tags: plotting, animation, scoping

Can someone tell me why this doesn't plot/animate?

```
x = Xm Cos[ω t + ϕ];
v = -ω Xm Sin[ω t + ϕ]; 
a = -ω^2 Xm Cos[ω t + ϕ];
Animate[Plot[{x, v, a}, {t, -12.5, 12}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, DarkGreen}], 
 {{ω, 1.57}, 0, 6.28}, {{ϕ, 0}, 0, 10}, {{Xm, 1}, 0, 3}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

If I move the definitions of the functions into the plot parameters instead of the x,v, and a variables, it will then work. Why can't I use the variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make the definition as function of all the variables.

```
x[ω_, ϕ_, t_, Xm_] := Xm*Cos[ω t + ϕ]; 
v[ω_, ϕ_, t_, Xm_] := -ω*Xm*Sin[ω t + ϕ]; 
a[ω_, ϕ_, t_, Xm_] := -ω^2*Xm*Cos[ω t + ϕ];

Animate[
Plot[{x[ω, ϕ, t, Xm], v[ω, ϕ, t, Xm], a[ω, ϕ,t, Xm]}, {t, -12.5, 12}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}], 
{{ω, 1.57}, 0, 6.28}, {{ϕ, 0}, 0, 10}, {{Xm, 1}, 0, 3}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: You don't really need to include `t` as it isn't localized by `Animate[ ]`- I would do the same nevertheless

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use the [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) [scoping construct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/9490)

```
With[{
  x = Xm Cos[ω t + ϕ],
  v = -ω Xm Sin[ω t + ϕ],
  a = -ω^2 Xm Cos[ω t + ϕ]
  },
 Animate[Plot[{x, v, a}, {t, -12.5, 12},
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, DarkGreen}],
  {{ω, 1.57}, 0, 6.28}, {{ϕ, 0}, 0, 10}, {{Xm, 1}, 0, 3},
  AnimationRunning -> False]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Both of these are very helpful, thanks.

Comment: For the future, can you help me understand _why_ I must do this?